# Ionic 2: when pushing a page, an unexpected margin appears

Tags: javascript, angular, margin, ionic2

I have some pages in my Ionic 2 project.
The pages theirselves are ok, but when I push them from another page, an unexpected "margin-top" element appears under the header!

Here's the code of one of the interested pages:

```
 <ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Title
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>...
```

Here's an image of the problem!

[image]

PS. Another info: that element in the middle seems to cover the ion-content when scrolling down.

Answer (score 0):

Click on `scroll-content` in the `Elements` inspector and check in `Styles` section where this margin came from.

**Update**: similar issue https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/too-much-margin-on-scroll-content-when-using-tabs-on-android/58522/3

Comment: That scroll-element isn't generated by me, but by Ionic. In fact, under `Styles`, there is no source that gave me that margin-top. I think it is created by Ionic because if I remove it, the content goes behind the header a bit, but where is that "126px" coming from?

Comment: looks like the same problem https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/too-much-margin-on-scroll-content-when-using-tabs-on-android/58522/3

Comment: Oh perfect, in other words I'm screwed until the next release XD